# How to prevent redundancy in junction object?

Tags: junction-object

I have 3  objects - Student, Course and Enrollment(Junction object for student and course).

Student's fields - student number(text 80), student first name(text 25), student last name(text 25), no of courses( rollup summary (count enrollment)), student email(email)

Course's field - course number(text 80), course title(text 50), no of students(rollup summary (count enrollment)), max capacity (number), available spots(formula number)

Enrollment's fields - course (master detail(course), student(master detail (student)), enrollment number(auto number)

Functionality I want in student page - enroll student in course

Functionality I want in course page - view info of related student

I created 2 master detail relationships in enrollment with student and course being masters to achieve this. I can do both functionalities but it creates redundancy(same students can be enrolled in 1 course).

For solution I want to concatenate student number and course number with work flow rule. I am having syntax error "Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (true or false).".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a Text (40 character long) Unique Index External Id field, and a Process Builder/Flow/Workflow Rule that assigns the Student+Course Id values. The system won't allow the junction to duplicate, instead providing an error message about a duplicate value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. but when I tried to concat the student and course fields in enrollment object through process builder and workflow rule, the error saying "The formula expression is invalid: Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (true or false)." as I use formula to evaluate.

Comment: @MitDesai Can you please update this question to include the setup you tried so far? Please be meticulous with the details so we can help you further.

Comment: I have updated the question, apologies if I am still missing something. Hope you have the required details now, if not I will provide. thanks

Comment: It worked. I used process builder instead. thanks a lot